# Restart Nginx or reload certificate cache on cert change

Tags: django, docker, ssl, nginx

**Background:**

I am running an app inside Docker, that will be managed by random users that do often not have any knowledge about Docker itself. I am building the app to be as much configurable from the webserver itself as possible.

It runs 3 non-root containers:

- Container 1: Gunicorn,Django,Certbot
- Container 2: Nginx
- Container 3: Postgresql

I am able to let the Django app run certbot via the website itself to get a certificate and copy the certificate into the volume that nginx is using. But the old or self-signed certificate seems to be cached by nginx on startup and so the new certificate is not used until a restart of nginx.

And here is the problem, I must now restart nginx or somehow reload the certificates automatically. Either by triggering the restart from the Django container to the Nginx Container maybe via a curl or something. Or I can use something like watchdog to watch the files for a file change.

**Question:**

What is the best approach to reload nginx automatically if a certificate changes? Or can I purge the certificate cache of the certificates even without restarting the server? What is your suggestion here?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 14):

A reload should be enough to load new certs.

Some options:

- Use host cron to reload nginx

`0 */6 * * * docker exec <nginx_container_name> nginx -s reload`

- Use certbot deploy hook (you need to run certbot in the nginx container or think of a way to make this deploy hook remote)

```
/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini:
deploy-hook = nginx -s reload
```

Comment: even when I reload the nginx I'm getting the same cert

Comment: I'd recommend using ```nginx -t && nginx -t reload```, then any invalid configuration will not result in your site going down in the middle of the night.

Comment: Might be a typo: should that be `nginx -t && nginx -s reload` instead?

Comment: `nginx -t` does not help in this case (of `nginx -s reload`), which already does the test and stops reloading if the config is wrong. Quote from the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html): ... `it checks the syntax validity of the new configuration file and tries to apply the configuration provided in it.` ... `Otherwise, the master process rolls back the changes and continues to work with the old configuration.`

Comment: @SOALABDELDJALLIL notice that if you tested a few minutes before, you may have a keepalive connection to a still running old worker. Either wait for all old workers to exit or open a new browser (or private window) and test from there

Comment: Some strongly suggest a more reliable`deploy-hook = systemctl reload nginx` instead of `nginx -s reload`.